# Authenticating dependent models in Spring / Grails

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, grails, grails-orm

I have a domain model structure laid out in GORM like:

```
User -< Company -< Product
```

These are mapped to RESTFUL routes similar to:

```
/company/1
/company/1/product/6
```

The currently logged in user is available in controllers as `user`.

Given this ownership structure, I want to ensure:

- a user can't access company they don't own
- and can't access products that are not associated with companies they own.

Is there a general, declarative approach to handling this Spring (or in Grails)?  The obvious approach of:

```
if (product.company.user != user) throw new Exception()
```

...in an application controller seems brittle, especially as the object hierarchy expands.

Comment: This https://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-acl plugin can be a good candidate for your problem.